# Rails is not currently installed on this system yet I've already installed it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I'm going round in circles getting the "Rails is not installed on this system" message in Terminal, yet it tells me I've just installed it.

```
Simons-MacBook-Pro:~ Simon$ sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-5.0.2
Parsing documentation for rails-5.0.2
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
Simons-MacBook-Pro:~ Simon$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, 
simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
Simons-MacBook-Pro:~ Simon$
```

Is there somewhere in particular I should be installing it?

Comment: What shell are you using? For me, I'd get a `unknown command` error if there was nothing called `rails`, so it seems like there's _something_ there. Did you try re-running `sudo gem install rails` again, and seeing if it works after that? Also, your last paragraph is irrelevant to the actual question, and makes the whole thing come off as more of a rant; I'd suggest removing it.

Comment: You should use `rvm`: https://rvm.io/.  Using the default Ruby on Mac can be challenging, which you're discovering.  Just follow the instructions there.

Comment: have you tried running `gem install rails` without the sudo? also, i second that you absolutely should use rvm.

Comment: If you're using rbenv, type `rbenv rehash`, or restart your console.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a step back and read http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-setup-for-mac-osx/ to get started properly. Trying to globally install Ruby and Rails will eventually work, but unless you're planning on only working on one Rails project ever, you'll eventually need a Ruby version manager and the tooling it provides to isolate each project.

Comment: Run `gem env` and copy/paste the output into your question, formatted for readability. It looks like you have a sandbox manager, like rbenv or RVM installed but don't show anything confirming it.

Comment: "why is there such a reliance on the Terminal, what wrong with a good GUI?"? You're programming a scripting language on a computer. Computers have command-lines to give us absolute control of the system. GUIs sit in a layer above the command-line and, while they're useful and we use them a lot, they're not the layer we want when we want absolute control for configuring or administering a system. When the mouse dies or the system won't register clicks the GUI is worthless. I'd recommend considering the CLI your friend, embrace it, and get to know it well.

Comment: QPaysTaxes that last comment was definitely a bit of venting. Removed.

Comment: @theTinMan Terminal has been a steep learning curve for me so far. Getting there step by step though. I do have RVM installed, but looks like I've solved the issue for now. Thanks.

Comment: We spend 50% of our time at the CLI where I work, and the other 50% in browsers and editors. And the other 50% trying to figure out why people did things the way they did in code we have to support.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  Found I had another copy in another path.  Deleted it and moved it into the same directory where I wanted to create the new app.

```
$sudo rails where
```

allowed me to find it.